# SailsJS: Requests choking at database query via models

Tags: node.js, sails.js, sails-postgresql

We have SailsJS app with postgresql adapter. Requests made to server chokes at database query via models. i.e Users.find(). Database server is up and running, connection string is correct and in place in datastore.js under `default` head

My guess is that it is not able to make connection to database, but it is also not failing with any error. How this can be debugged

Answer (score 0):

Setup your models to use the Postgres adapter the config/models.js file will need to be updated:

```
module.exports.models = {
   connection: 'postgres'
}
```